# Is this sufficient validation/sanitization for my simple webapp?

Tags: python, web-applications, security

Firstly, I'm a novice at web development.  I am making a simple mod_wsgi webapp that has two text fields to accept user input.

The first input, nnodes, must be an integer between 0-30.

The second input, size, must be an integer or float between 0-20.

Here is the validation/sanitization I have in my script so far.  Seeing as how I use input redirection later in the script, I was hoping that someone could comment on whether I'd be susceptible to any significant malicious threats:

```
    nnodes = escape(nnodes)
    size = escape(size)

    if nnodes.isdigit() and int(nnodes) in range(31):
        pass
    elif nnodes=='':
        response_body=html % ' '
        status='200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),('Content-Length',str(len(response_body)))] 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]
    else:
        response_body=html % 'Please enter the number of malignant nodes as a whole number between 0 and 30.'
        status='200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),('Content-Length',str(len(response_body)))] 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]

###Validate that the tumorsize is a float between 0-25. 
    try:
        size=='' or float(size)
        pass
    except:
        response_body=html % 'Please enter the tumor size as a number between 0 and 25.'
        status='200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),('Content-Length',str(len(response_body)))] 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]

    if 0<=float(size)<=25:
        pass
    elif size=='':
        response_body=html % ' '
        status='200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),('Content-Length',str(len(response_body)))] 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]
    else:
        response_body=html % 'Please enter the tumor size as a number between 0 and 25.'
        status='200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'),('Content-Length',str(len(response_body)))] 
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [response_body]

###After the validation, I use input redirection to pass the input to an R script.  I know this is not optimal but I can't get the Rpy2 module to work on my server.  
###I also know that input redirection can open an app up to shell injection, but that is why I am asking you all if I've done sufficient validation and sanitization.

commandString="/home/usr/bin/R --no-save --quiet --slave --args " + str(nnodes) + " " + str(size) + " </home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/webcalc.R"
subprocess.call(commandString,shell=True)
```

I appreciate any advice you all have to give.

Comment: As an aside, you should really be using a framework. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is nice and simple, and allows you to get rid of a lot of that boilerplate. If you need something more database-driven, you might consider Django instead, since it has a nice built-in ORM and a bunch of other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Never trust the user" is reason enough. But "never trust the programmer" is another valid aphorism. Even though you might THINK your validation and sanitizing routines are ironclad, there could be a subtle bug that could allow malicious input through. Better safe than sorry.

I found a bit more about the R interpreter from the manpage. Apparently there is a -f argument that lets you specify an input file. So this whole thing can be fixed:

```
# Split out the filename for easier refactoring
r_script = '/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/webcalc.R'
# We can give an iterable to subprocess.call()
command_args = ['/home/usr/bin/R', '-f', r_script, '--no-save', '--quiet', '--slave', '--args', str(nnodes),
    str(size)]
# And since we don't need shell features like '<', shell=True goes away!
subprocess.call(command_args)
```

Note that it is still *very* important to validate and sanitize the input.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Colin.  I'm running in to a problem though.  Since `-f` is placed after `--args`, the R interpreter is treating `-f` like it is a command-line argument (just like `str(size)`).  When I place `-f` before `--args`, I get this error message:

`ERROR: option '-f' requires an argument`

Comment: @user1385991 I updated my example. You need to move the -f and it's argument before --args

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructive help, Colin.

Answer (score 0):

This code smells awful.  You are being very unclear with how you are enforcing rules.  Your code completely lacks abstraction.

At **NO POINT** should you use a try/catch all block when performing a validation check for security.   You don't know why an operation may fail unless you catch an specific exception type.  For all user data you should be able to check the type,  perform a cast, a check the value's range without throwing an exception.  Also, you should use a single method to display the error page.

> Complexity is the worst enemy of security.
>
> --Bruce Schneier

Comment: This is my first go at making a web app, and I wasn't a nuanced programmer to begin with, so it doesn't surprise me that it smells bad.  I'd like to learn some more about the things you are referring to, but Googling hasn't turned up very useful sites.  When I search "web app abstraction" I get abstracts on web app development.  Could you point me to a good resource or two on abstraction and the proper method to validate user data (you said check the type, perform a cast...)?